# React Native: Change Component (Text) on Navigator Pop

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native

I'm creating a Component/View that has a list of things to select from similar to a table view.

When I'm in View A I can jump to this table view by doing a navigator push. Once an item is selected I do a pop. However, I'd like a text component in View A to be updated with the appropriate value.

I was thinking of passing a reference to this text component but it doesn't sound right. Any other ways I could achieve that?

I couldn't find any table view that would work on both platforms, let me know if you have any good suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The React way to achieve this is to pass a `callback` function to a named attribute, let's say in this case `onSelect`.

```
MyParentComponent extends Component {
    ...
    MySelectHandler(value) {
        this.setState({
            valueSelected: value
        });
    },
    ...
}
```

Creating your picker component:

```
<MyCustomTableView onSelect={this.MySelectHandler}/>
```

And in your component:

```
MyCustomTableView extends Component {
    ...
    onValueSelected(value) {
        this.props.onSelect(value);
    }
    ...
}
```

Considering your "re-render" problem, React only updates Component who have changed depending on the previous state. As your inputs probably don't depend on the state, they don't get updated because nothing changed for them.

If you want to clear all your inputs when the `valueSelected` key state gets updated, you can use the lifecycle method `componentDidUpdate()`, and manually clear your inputs after each value update.

```
// In MyParentComponent
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    if (prevState.valueSelected !== this.state.valueSelected)
        this.refs.myInput.value = ''; // Do this for each input, you'll need to add a unique ref attribute for each one
}
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by passing {this} to the table view as a prop and calling this.props.parent.setState({selection: selectedThing}) in the table view.

I thought setState would re-render the whole view and get rid of any user inputs but it seems to only re-render changed components